# Avoid generating empty listitem versions

Tags: 2013, versioning, list-item, save

In our SharePoint farm there are some lists with the listitem versioning feature activated. It works great, but it creates also a new version if a user saves without editing any fields. I know that the user should click 'cancel'... but is there a way to fix this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: If you want to avoid versioning of items please check this link, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-and-configure-versioning-for-a-list-on-a-site-97d9a754-c7e3-4a8e-97aa-35598b28d86c

Comment: I don't want to disable it, i want to avoid to have empty versioning, which occurrs when a user start to edit an item, then instead of clicking `cancel` (in order to go back) it clicks `save` even if he did any changes.

Comment: No, because SP does not check WHAT changed... so to SharePoint a save is a change. Workaround is to add a Workflow and check WHAT changed yourself... but that requires extra tracking of all fields you'd have to do yourself.. Maybe the Event Receiver Coding guys can suggest a check after an Item has saved and compare it with the previous version. Educate your users or put an extra confirm on the Save button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a script in C# in order to delete them:

```
using (var portal = new SPSite(AppConfig.UrlPortal))
{
    foreach (SPWeb web in portal.AllWebs) // iterate all webs
    {
        foreach (SPList list in web.Lists) // iterate all lists
        {
            var items = list.GetItems(new SPQuery()); // define your query if you need

            foreach (SPListItem item in items) // iterate all items
            {
                var versionsCount = item.Versions.Count;
                if (versionsCount > 1)
                {
                    var toDelete = new List<SPListItemVersion>();

                    for (var i = 0; i < versionsCount - 1; i++) // iterate versions
                    {
                        var actVersion = item.Versions[i];
                        var preVersion = item.Versions[i + 1];

                        var hasChanges = false;

                        foreach (SPField field in actVersion.Fields) // iterate fields
                        {
                            var name = field.StaticName;
                            var actVal = Convert.ToString(actVersion[name]);
                            var preVal = Convert.ToString(preVersion[name]);

                            if (actVal != preVal) // check if the field value changed
                            {
                                switch (name)
                                {
                                    case "_UIVersion":
                                    case "_UIVersionString":
                                    case "owshiddenversion":
                                    case "Editor":
                                    case "Modified":
                                    case "_IsCurrentVersion":
                                    case "AppEditor":
                                        break; // define which field not to consider

                                    default:
                                        hasChanges = true;
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (!hasChanges && !actVersion.IsCurrentVersion) // the current version cannot be deleted
                        {
                            toDelete.Add(actVersion);
                        }
                    }

                    toDelete.Sort(new SPListItemVersionComparer()); // you have to sort the items, otherwise it throws an exeption

                    foreach (var v in toDelete) // delete them
                    {
                        v.Delete();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it will be helpful.